# can not push my cloned project to the Repositpry

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I cloned a project from github and work on it. Now, after doing many changes I can not push to the master or even new branch and I get this error:

```
Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/anotherperson/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I also tried to Create pull request (I really do not know to how should handle my edits in github) and the error message is the same.

Comment: Did you fork the repo?

Comment: "error: 403",  make sure you have `write permission` to the repo.

Comment: @Mureinik yes I forled the repo and I set the proper username and password of github

Comment: @sajibkhan how I can find out the permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow is wrong. By default, you won't have permissions to a forked repo, so you can't push to it - as you've seen, that will result in a 403 error.

Instead, you should push the changes to your own fork:

```
$ git push origin mybranch
```

And then create a pull request from your branch. Just use the web GUI to navigate to your fork of the repo, and you should see am option to create a pull request.

Comment: you right. my follow was wrong and also I tried for pull request from Android Studio and It was not working. thanks